# Why did David think he sinned when numbering the people?

Tags: david, 2-samuel

In 2.Samuel 24, the Lord asks David to "Go, number Israel and Judah." However, once David has done this, after nine months of work, he suddenly thinks that he has sinned greatly in numbering the people.

I cannot understand why David thinks that he has sinned, especially that he was following the Lord's instructions... And what is so wrong with counting the people ? After all this is done many times in the Bible (e.g.: Numbers, etc.)...

Can anyone help me with this one ?

Comment: related: [Who incited David to take a census?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1296)

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://$SITEURL$/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) This is a great question, but [it's already been asked here before.](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1296/423) Be sure to head over to the original question to read some additional great answers! I hope to hear more great questions (and answers) from you in the future!