# Why did God punish David for numbering Israel?

Tags: david, 1-chronicles

In 1 Chronicles Chapter 21 it is written:

> And Satan stood up against Israel, and provoked David to number Israel.

What was the great sin that david did in numbering Israel, and why is this sin given extra importance by saying, "Satan stood up against Israel"?

Comment: Hi Rikku, if your question is different from the "[duplicate](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/who-incited-david-to-take-a-census-and-whats-wrong-with-taking-a-census-anyway)" please [edit] to make this clear, thanks.

Comment: *What was the great sin that David did in numbering Israel ?* - Numbering presupposes knowledge of *numbers* (obviously)... and, as we only too well know, when Hindu-Arabic numerals were introduced to Western Europe in the High Middle Ages, it spiked a tremendous advance in science and knowledge, ultimately resulting in the rise of modernity and the Enlightenment, which, in its turn, generated a significant decline in religious belief. Clearly, God wanted to spare the ancient Israelites from sharing a similar fate.